Prove the Largest Eigenvalue of a Markov Chain is $0$
I am trying to prove that for a Continuous Time Markov Chain (CTMC), the largest eigenvalue of the transition rate matrix is always $0$.
Consider a CTMC with transition rate matrix $Q$.
Here, we know that for $Q$:
$$ q_{ij} \geq 0 \text{ for } i \neq j \text{ (off-diagonal elements are non-negative)} $$
$$ q_{ii} = -\sum_{j \neq i} q_{ij} \text{ (diagonal elements are negative sums of off-diagonal elements)} $$
$$ \sum_j q_{ij} = 0 \text{ for all i (row sums are zero)} $$
Now, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $Q$ with corresponding eigenvector $v$. By definition, we know that:
$$ Qv = \lambda v $$
I define $i^*$ as the index where  $|v_i|$ attains its maximum:
$$ |v_{i^*}| = \max_i |v_i| $$
We can the write this as follows:
$$ \sum_j q_{i^*j}v_j = \lambda v_{i^*} $$
I struggled with the following part. To continue the proof, we need to eventually use the triangle inequality to compare the sizes of both terms. Taking the absoloute value:
$$ \left|\sum_j q_{i^*j}v_j\right| = |\lambda| |v_{i^*}| $$
Looking at the left hand side for the above equation, we can use the triangle inequality to write:
$$ \left|\sum_j q_{i^*j}v_j\right| \leq \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| |v_j| $$
Doing some manipulation (i.e. relying on the fact that $|v_{i^*}|$ is the maximum, see note 1)
$$ \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| |v_j| \leq |v_{i^*}| \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| $$
Again, putting it back together:
$$ |\lambda| |v_{i^*}| \leq |v_{i^*}| \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| $$
If $v_{i^*} \neq 0$ which must be true for an eigenvector, i.e. length of the eigenvector should not be $0$), we can divide both sides by $|v_{i^*}|$:
$$ |\lambda| \leq \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| $$
From the properties of $Q$ , we know that (see note 2):
$$ \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| = \sum_{j \neq i^*} q_{i^*j} - q_{i^*i^*} = -q_{i^*i^*} - q_{i^*i^*} = -2q_{i^*i^*} $$
Therefore:
$$ |\lambda| \leq -2q_{i^*i^*} $$
Since $ q_{i^*i^*} \leq 0$  we have:
$$ |\lambda| \leq 0 $$
The only way this inequality can be satisfied is if:
$$ \lambda = 0 $$
In my opinion, the desired result have been proven.
Am I correct?
Thanks!


Note 1:

$$\sum_j |q_{i*j}||v_j| \leq |v_{i*}| \sum_j |q_{i*j}|$$
Using the definition of $|v_{i*}|$ as the maximum absolute value among all components of the eigenvector:
$$|v_{i*}| = \max_j |v_j|$$
This means that for all $j$:
$$|v_j| \leq |v_{i*}|$$
Looking at the Left Hand Side:
$$|q_{i*j}||v_j|$$
Replace each $|v_j|$ with $|v_{i*}|$ (since $|v_{i*}|$ is greater than or equal to all $|v_j|$):
$$|q_{i*j}||v_j| \leq |q_{i*j}||v_{i*}|$$
This is true for each term in the sum. So we can write:
$$\sum_j |q_{i*j}||v_j| \leq \sum_j |q_{i*j}||v_{i*}|$$
The $|v_{i*}|$ term is constant with respect to the summation, so we can factor it out:
$$\sum_j |q_{i*j}||v_j| \leq |v_{i*}| \sum_j |q_{i*j}|$$
This is the intended result


Note 2:

Here is my attempt to justify this:
$$ \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| = \sum_{j \neq i^*} q_{i^*j} - q_{i^*i^*} = -q_{i^*i^*} - q_{i^*i^*} = -2q_{i^*i^*} $$
For a CTMC:
$$ q_{ij} \geq 0 \text{ for } i \neq j $$
$$ q_{ii} = -\sum_{j \neq i} q_{ij} $$
$$ \sum_j q_{ij} = 0 \text{ for all i} $$
Now, let's look at the sum $\sum_j |q_{i^*j}|$. We can split this into two parts:
$$ \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| = |q_{i^*i^*}| + \sum_{j \neq i^*} |q_{i^*j}| $$
We know that $q_{i^*i^*}$ is negative (it's a diagonal element), so $|q_{i^*i^*}| = -q_{i^*i^*}$. For all other terms, $q_{i^*j} \geq 0$ when $j \neq i^*$, so $|q_{i^*j}| = q_{i^*j}$. Thus:
$$ \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| = -q_{i^*i^*} + \sum_{j \neq i^*} q_{i^*j} $$
By definition, the following is true:
$$ \sum_j q_{i^*j} = 0 $$
This means:
$$ q_{i^*i^*} + \sum_{j \neq i^*} q_{i^*j} = 0 $$
$$ \sum_{j \neq i^*} q_{i^*j} = -q_{i^*i^*} $$
Substituting this back into the above equation:
$$ \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| = -q_{i^*i^*} + (-q_{i^*i^*}) = -2q_{i^*i^*} $$
This is the intended result


Note 3:  A numerical example for Note 2

Consider a CTMC with three states and matrix $Q$:
$$ Q = \begin{bmatrix} 
-3 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & -4 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & -3
\end{bmatrix} $$
For row 1 $(i^* = 1)$:
$$ \sum_j |q_{1j}| = |-3| + |2| + |1| = 3 + 2 + 1 = 6 $$
$$ -2q_{11} = -2(-3) = 6 $$
For row 2 $(i^* = 2)$:
$$ \sum_j |q_{2j}| = |1| + |-4| + |3| = 1 + 4 + 3 = 8 $$
$$ -2q_{22} = -2(-4) = 8 $$
For row 3 $(i^* = 3)$:
$$ \sum_j |q_{3j}| = |2| + |1| + |-3| = 2 + 1 + 3 = 6 $$
$$ -2q_{33} = -2(-3) = 6 $$
As we can see, for each row $i^*$:
$$ \sum_j |q_{i^*j}| = -2q_{i^*i^*} $$
.

Look up Gerschgorin's theorem. That tells you the real part of every eigenvalue will be nonpositive.

Thanks... will look ... so it means my work is not correct?

Not necessarily, it's a wheel that is quite painless to reinvent.

what does "largest eigenvalue" of a matrix containing non-real eigenvalues mean? If you are interested in largest real component of all eigenvalues you need to say so; in such a case consider that $\exp\big(Q\big)$ is a markov chain
